# I cannot get operator+ function to compile, have I maybe made a mistake with one of the constructors?

Tags: c++11

This operator will receive a string with the format "x,y."
x represents an x coordinate and y represents a y coordinate. If the
coordinates are valid (that is within the valid range of the chess
board) then the appropriate variables should be set with these
variables. If the coordinates are invalid,
then nothing should happen.

operator<<: It also prints out (with a new line at the end), a message in the
following format:
b rook at [0,0]
The side is printed first, then the piece type followed by the coordinates at the end.
``This message must be sent to the output variable.

```
Piece::Piece(){    
}

Piece::Piece(Piece *newPiece){
*newPiece = Piece;
}

Piece::Piece(string pType, char side, int x, int y){
//string pT = pType;
//char s = side;
}

Piece::~Piece(){

}

char Piece::getSide(){
return side;
}

string Piece::getPieceType(){
    return PieceType;
}

int Piece::getX(){
   return xPos;
}

int Piece::getY(){
    return yPos;
}

void Piece::setX(int x){
    xPos = x;
}

void Piece::setY(int y){
    yPos = y;
}

void Piece::operator[](int pos){
    cin>>pos;
    if(pos != 0 || pos != 1){
        cout<<"Invalid Index"<<endl;
}
    else{
        if(pos == 0 ){
            cout<<"x coord"<<xPos;
            }
        if(pos == 1){
            cout<<"y cord"<<yPos;
            }
    }
}
//Everything above compiled

Piece& Piece::operator+(string move){

    if(xPos<=side && yPos<=side){
        move = xPos;",";yPos;
        return move;
    }   
    return 0;
}



ostream& Piece::operator<<(ostream& output,const Piece& t ){
    t = Piece;
    output = side + PieceType + pos;
    cout<<output;

}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is too little information. What is the issue? Compile error? Runtime error? Wrong result?

Comment: Do you have an assignment operator looking like this `Piece& Piece::operator=(Piece*);` ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], the full error message,  compiler name and version, OS.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to call `new` inside the constructor.

Since you're calling `new Piece` in the constructor of `Piece`, you will end up in an infinite loop. The expression `new Piece` again invokes the constructor of `Piece`, which again calls `new Piece`, which invokes the constructor, ...

Also, think a second about what's happening here: `*newPiece = new Piece;` is constructing a new `Piece` object and assigning the result to the *local* pointer value `newPiece`. After the constructor ends (which in your case, it never does, because of the infinite loop), that local variable goes out of scope and your new `Piece` is lost.

Comment: Removing "new" in the constructor resulted in a compliation error.

Comment: @Picanha I am not surprised by that, but that doesn't change the fact that the constructor as written is incorrect. As has been pointed out in the comments, the example code you provided is incomplete, so there are likely to be additional issues in your code that we are not aware of.